# Is an isoentropic process also closed?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I'm trying to solve a problem where I'm asked to determine the $T_f/T_i$ ratio of an isoentropic expansion for a system with a particular $u(v,s)$ function. I have found a correct solution but at the expense of assuming that the chemical potential is invariant, $d\mu=0$.

Obviously an isoentropic process is adiabatic, but does it also have to be closed?

EDIT: I'll add that the problem doesn't specify the system being open or closed, that's the spark for this question.

Comment: what is a "closed" process?

Comment: "*Obviously an isoentropic process is adiabatic*" Why? I can maintain constant system entropy if I allow an irreversible process to occur while also cooling the system to exactly offset the entropy increase. Adiabatic reversibility implies constant entropy, but the reverse isn't necessarily true.

Comment: @hyportnex I guess my terminology isn't on point, but what I mean is a process in which material neither enters or leaves the system.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I assume that, using the same reasoning, the process could be isoentropic if, for example, the system were losing material but also heating up, correct? Meaning my assumption isn't justified.

Comment: Yes, matter carries entropy.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thanks, I'll post another question with my solution method, perhaps someone can spot why it works.

Comment: @agaminon "Obviously an isentropic process is adiabatic, but does it also have to
be closed?" No it doesn't have to be closed. A reversible adiabatic turbine is an example of an isentropic process for an open system.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is *not* closed we need information about what exactly is going with the flows in and out of the system. Since not enough information is given I will assume that (i) a fixed amount of matter (ii) expands adiabatically and (iii) reversibly from (iv) $v_1$ to $v_2$.

Adiabatic plus reversible is isentropic, therefore $s_1=s_2=s$. Since we are given $u(v,s)$, the initial and final temperatures are
$$
   T_1 = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_{v_1}
$$
$$
   T_2 = \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_{v_2}
$$

**Comments**

1. The calculation does not require the condition $d\mu = 0$, in fact, $\mu$ is **not** constant during expansion (we can easily demonstrate using ideal gas). The calculation does require $dn = 0$, though.
2. The calculation applies to a closed system (e.g. a gas in cylinder with a piston)
3. The calculation also applies to steady state flow of one stream. In this case we imagine that we follow a fixed amount of matter as it flows from inlet to outlet conditions and apply the above solution.
4. If there are more flows in and out of the system we need to have information about them before we can solve the problem.